# Access-Control-Allow-Origin: same-origin & recaptcha & YouTube-Videos

Tags: javascript, http-headers, recaptcha, cross-origin-opener-policy, cross-origin-embedder-policy

I have a problem on my website. I used ffmpeg.wasm which needs SharedArrayBuffers. This requires that I include as header Access-Control-Allow-Origin: same-origin. The problem is that blocks both my YouTube videos and my libraries like recaptcha.
I am completely lost as to how to use both. Does anyone have any tips on this? Can't figure it out from the doc.

Thanks for all the answers.

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: same-origin');
    header('Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp');

    //Just for testing
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.google.com');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://ajax.googleapis.com');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET');
?>

<html lang="de">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>AtmosFX-Translator Online</title>
        <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
```

Even with the recommended headers on my site I get the message from my js that I am using a SAB.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is caused by `Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp`. It's necessary to continue using SharedArrayBuffer, but you also need `Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin` as well.

These are requirements to adopt "cross-origin isolation" and here's a guide how to enable it: https://web.dev/cross-origin-isolation-guide/